# Wireless breaks after closing laptop

Tags: linux-mint, wifi, laptop

I am running Linux Mint 17.2 on a Dell Inspiron 6400 laptop. Since ndiswrapper failed to install the drivers for my internal network card, I am using an external usb netgear WN111 v2 card. It works, but whenever I close and open my laptop lid, wireless won't work, even though it stays connected to the network. why does this happen, and can it be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Is your networkmanager.conf correct? Thats the first thing that came to my mind...

```
/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

    [ifupdown]
    managed=true
```